# R for dataset "undefined columns selected" in wordcloud due to column 0 auto-generation of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, word-cloud

However, it says "undefined columns selected." I am really bad at R and I am trying to select the 1st column. Column 0 is the auto-generated row number.

```
cd <- data.frame(combineData$DogName)


 figPath = system.file("dog.png",package = "wordcloud2")
wordcloud2(data = cd[,"combineData.DogName"], figPath = figPath, size = 1.5,color = "skyblue")
```

I've tried removing column 0 and tried a lot of other ways. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give a sample from your combinedata dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1. *"Column 0 is the auto-generated row number"* There is no 0 column in an R `data.frame`.
2. I don't understand what's the purpose of `cd` which contains only a single column from `combineData`.

From `?wordcloud2`

> data                 A data frame including word and freq in each column

So the `data` argument of `wordcloud2` needs to be a `data.frame` with two columns.

Here is a minimal reproducible example based on some sample data

```
library(wordcloud2)
set.seed(2018)
df <- aggregate(
    freq ~ word,
    data = data.frame(
        word = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = T),
        freq = sample(10:100, 100, replace = T)),
    FUN = sum)

wordcloud2(df)
```

[image]

Comment: @iod Actually it *will* be `combineData.DogName` following OPs code. Check with `cd <- data.frame(mtcars$mpg)`: the column name is `mtcars.mpg` not just `mpg`.

Comment: Huh... Never knew that. LSNED.